# Please remind me of how this technique works ...

Tags: sequences-and-series

We had a high school mathematics teacher who taught us a cool technique that I've forgotten. It can be used, for example, for developing a formula for the sum of squares for the first "n" integers. You start by making a column for Sn, and then determine the differences until you get a constant. See the picture.

[image: example - sorry about the rotated picture]
(sorry about the rotated picture)

**How do you proceed from here to the formula?**

Comment: A helpful discussion here of the *finite difference* approach: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/316753/215011

Answer (score 4):

Every polynomial that takes integer values over the integers can be represented with respect to the binomial base as a linear combination with integer coefficients. In our case:

$$ n^2 = \color{blue}{2}\binom{n}{2}+\color{blue}{1}\binom{n}{1}+\color{blue}{0}\binom{n}{0} \tag{1}$$
And that leads to:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}n^2 = 2\binom{N+1}{3}+1\binom{N+1}{2}+0\binom{N+1}{1} = \frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}.\tag{2} $$
The blue coefficients appearing in $(1)$ can be computed through the forward difference operator:
$$ \begin{array}{ccccccccc} \color{blue}{0} && 1 && 4 && 9 && 16 \\ &\color{blue}{1} && 3 && 5 && 7 && \\ && \color{blue}{2} && 2 && 2 &&& \end{array}\tag{3}$$

Another example, for $n^3$.
$$ \begin{array}{ccccccccc} \color{blue}{0} && 1 && 8 && 27 && 64 \\ &\color{blue}{1} && 7 && 19 && 37 && \\ && \color{blue}{6} && 12 && 18 &&& \\ &&& \color{blue}{6} && 6 \end{array}\tag{3bis}$$
Gives:
$$ n^3 = \color{blue}{6}\binom{n}{3}+\color{blue}{6}\binom{n}{2}+\color{blue}{1}\binom{n}{1}\tag{1bis} $$
hence:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}n^3 = 6\binom{N+1}{4}+6\binom{N+1}{3}+1\binom{N+1}{2}=\left(\frac{N(N+1)}{2}\right)^2.\tag{2bis}$$

You may be also interested in knowing that our "magic blue numbers" just depend on [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html).

Comment: What/where is the background for step (1)? Thanks.

Comment: @EricDuncan: $(1)$ is a consequence of $(3)$. Read it this way: $(3)\mapsto (1)\mapsto (2)$ and $(3bis)\mapsto (1bis)\mapsto (2bis)$.

Comment: I'm afraid that without a worked example of the forward difference operator , I'm clueless as to where the blue coefficients come from. I'll do some background reading before I post again.

Comment: @EricDuncan: there are two worked examples here. In $(3)$ and $(3bis)$, every coefficient is the difference between the coefficient at its top right and the coefficient at its top left. The blue coefficients are the first coefficients of every line.

Answer (score 0):

- backgrounded on the fact that the difference of two consecutive squares is an odd number:

$(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$

the difference of two consecutive odd numbers is always $2$ thus the self-saying technique.

So when we proceed to find a square $n^2$ we sum up all odd numbers from 1 to $2n-1$ which is an arithmetic sequence of distance 2.

$n^2=\frac{n(2n)}{2}=\frac{\frac{(2n)(2n)}{2}}{2}=\frac{\frac{(2n-1)(2n)}{2}+n}{2}=\frac{\binom{2n}{2}+n}{2}$

Also we note that

$n^2=\frac{\frac{(2n)(2n)}{2}}{2}=\frac{\frac{(2n+1)(2n)}{2}-n}{2}=\frac{\binom{2n+1}{2}-n}{2}$

Summing up the two sums of two formulas  $$\sum_n{\frac{\binom{2i}{2}+n}{2}}+\sum_n{\frac{\binom{2i+1}{2}-n}{2}}=\sum_n{\frac{\binom{2i}{2}+\binom{2i+1}{2}}{2}}=\sum_{2n+1}{\frac{\binom{i}{2}}{2}}=2\sum{i^2}$$ is just the sum of values in second column of pascal triangle (even and odd binomials) until $2n+1$, divided by 2.

```
    1
    1 1 
    1 2  |1 |
    1 3  |3 | 1
    1 4  |6 | 4  1
    1 5  |10| 10 5  1
    1 6  |15| 20 15 6 1
    . .   \  \
    . .    \  \
    . .     \  \
    1 7   21 \35\ .  .  .  .
```

Summing up the second column will result in the next row/column situated pascal value, which is known to be $\binom{2n+2}{3}$

So ... $$2\sum_n{i^2}=\frac{\binom{2n+2}{3}}{2}=\frac{\frac{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}{6}}{2}$$